# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascripts" src="try/jquery-1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="slider.js"></script>
<script>
    var slider = new slider( $('div.slider ul'), ('#slider-nav'));
    lider.nav.show().find('button').on('click', function() {


    slider.setCoordinates( $(this).data('dir') );

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The path to your jQuery script is most likely incorrect.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service. Please ask a *question* (something with a `?` behind), and show some effort in solving your problems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`text/javascripts` is not the correct MIME type for a script file. `text/javascript` is. Most browsers will reject the bad MIME type and not run the script.